# JavaScript - Function constructor works without the 'new' keyword

Tags: javascript, function, oop, constructor, new-operator

We all know that it's bad to call a JavaScript constructor function without the 'new' keyword.
So why does this:

```
Function("a", "b", "return a + b")(1, 1); // returns "2"
```

Return the same value as this?:

```
new Function("a", "b", "return a + b")(1, 1); // Also returns "2"
```

And is there any harm (or benefit) in omitting the 'new' key word in this instance?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It's not a duplicate because nowhere in the linked question is the `Function` constructor mentioned.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy No, I do not have a vested interest in keeping this question open. I could close this question immediately. However, I do believe that it is genuinely a new question because it addresses something that the linked question doesn't. To a person looking for an answer on StackOverflow, nothing is more annoying than having to follow a duplicate link and then finding that they have to extrapolate the answer for themselves. It's okay to have duplicates as long as it's new: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Function` constructor creates a new function whether you call it with `new` or not.  That's just how it is written.  Constructors can be written that way, if desired.

From the [MDN page on the Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> Invoking the Function constructor as a function (without using the new
>   operator) has the same effect as invoking it as a constructor.

There is no harm or benefit or even any difference in using or not using the `new` operator with the `Function` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is indeed no harm of calling `Function` without the `new` keyword. In fact, I would advise against using `new` in your programs as much as possible: [stop using the `new` keyword](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#toc_1).

It would be much better to create a `new` function instead:

```
Function.prototype.new = function () {
    Factory.prototype = this.prototype;
    return new Factory(this, arguments);
};

function Factory(constructor, args) {
    return constructor.apply(this, args);
}
```

The advantage of doing so it that now you can create instances as follows:

```
function Foo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

var foo = Foo.new(1, 2);

// instead of

var foo = new Foo(1, 2);
```

What's the point? The point is that you can now do things like:

```
var foo = Foo.new.apply(Foo, [1, 2]);
```

Because `new` is a function you can do things to it like apply it to an array of arguments, etc. You can't do the same thing with the `new` keyword.

Anyway, getting back to the topic at hand the `Function` constructor can be called with or without the `new` keyword. It doesn't make any difference. Hence I would advise you not to use the `new` keyword at all. Not only does it save you a few keystrokes but also it can be used for things like:

```
Function.apply(null, ["a", "b", "return a + b"]);
```

This is especially useful if you don't know how many arguments you want the function to have beforehand.

Hope that helps.